# How to learn tantra vidya ? Any good master who teach us?

Tags: mantras, tantra, spirituality, yantra

I am searching for genuine tantra vidya course and gurus. Which is the best place where I can find the gurus who teach such course. If any genuine gurus please help me out. I come from hyderabad, India.

Comment: This question sounds opinion-based to me. - *"Any **good** master who teach us?"* - Opinion!

Comment: Read kularnava tantra. Lord Shiva described the qualities of a worthy shisya. When shisya is worthy, guru will come automatically.